# Can't find org.junit in Intellij with Gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, junit

I have gradle file configured as follows. In IDE, it doesn't resolve any of JUnit dependencies. Not sure what's wrong. I could see libraries added in the module. But imports still appear as unresolved in test files.

I tried with Eclipse and it worked fine. It's happening only with IntelliJ. Below is the snippet from my gradle file.

```
sourceSets {

integrationTest {
    compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
    runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    java {
        srcDirs = ['test_dir1', 'test_dir2']
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs = ['test_dir1', 'test_dir2']
    }
}
}


configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom(testCompile)
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom(testRuntime)
}


dependencies {

integrationTestCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
integrationTestCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.9.5'
integrationTestCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-mockito-release-full', version: '1.6.4'
}


task integrationTest(type: Test) {
testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

if(project.hasProperty("directoryFilter")) {
    include project.getProperty("directoryFilter")
    }
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('src')
        testSourceDirs += file('test')
        testSourceDirs += file('test_dir1')
        testSourceDirs += file('test_dir2')
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is your test class located in your project?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.

Comment: @JBNizet it's under Project-->test_dir1, test_dir2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. It's the version of Powermock against the version of JUnit. Seems IntelliJ doesn't like those two versions work with each other. Degrading Junit to 4.11 and Powermock to 1.5.5 did work for me.